# Failed to connect to us15.api.mailchimp.com port 443: Timed out

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am using mailchimp api to get records in my wordpress theme, sometime

```
Curl_exec
```

bring all records correctly but sometime not, I have tried with all other suggestion that was available online for example `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);` I try to make it 100 400 and 10 in the last argument but no success. I have tried other things too.

But when I check what the error is with this code

```
if ( curl_errno( $ch ) ) {
            print curl_error( $ch );
        }
```

I got `Failed to connect to us15.api.mailchimp.com port 443: Timed out`

Looking for help for perfect solution.

```
private function _raw_request($method, $args=array())
{      
    $args['apikey'] = $this->api_key;
    $url = $this->api_endpoint.'/'.$method.'.json';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');       
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $this->verify_ssl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($args));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if ( curl_errno( $ch ) ) {
            print curl_error( $ch );
        }


        curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you calling in HTTPS mode
you must add those
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
and
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);